# Segmentation fault with no pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

Here is my code and problem. The code compiles fine. But when I run it. After I enter the menu option in getMenuOption() "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" pops up. What is wrong?
I'm new to programming in general. Thanks for the help if its provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define CALCULATE_PI 'a'
#define CALCULATE_GEOMEAN 'b'
#define CALCULATE_HARMMEAN 'c'

void printInstructions (void);
void printMenuOptions (void);
int  runMenuOption ();
int  getMenuOption ();
int  getLimit ();
int  calculatePi ();
int  calculateGeoMean ();
int  calculateHarmonicMean ();

int main(void)
{
    printInstructions();

    printMenuOptions();

    runMenuOption(getMenuOption());

    return 0;

}

void printInstructions (void)
{
    printf("======================================================\n");
    printf("=  PI, Geometric Mean, and Harmonic Mean Calculator  =\n");
    printf("=  Please refer to the menu to choose calucaltion    =\n");
    printf("=Choose desired menu option and press enter to begin =\n");
    printf("=      Proceed to follow on-screen instructions      =\n");
    printf("======================================================\n\n\n");

    return;
}

void printMenuOptions (void)
{
    printf("3 choices: Please enter a VALID letter.\n");
    printf("Choice 'a'   = Calcualtes PI\n");
    printf("Choice 'b'   = Calculates Geometric Mean\n");
    printf("Choice 'c'   = Calculates Harmonic Mean\n\n");

    return;
 }

int runMenuOption (int getMenuOption())
{
    char option;
    double answer,
            Pi = 0.0,
            geoMean = 0.0;

    option = getMenuOption();

    switch (option)
    {
        case CALCULATE_PI:
            calculatePi(getLimit());
            answer = Pi;
            break;
        case CALCULATE_GEOMEAN:
            calculateGeoMean(getLimit());
            answer = geoMean;
        case CALCULATE_HARMMEAN:
            printf("Harmonic Mean");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Incorrect Character!\n");
            printf("Try again");
            break;
    }

    printf("Your answer is %5p", &answer);

    return 0;
}

int getMenuOption (void)
{
    char option;

    printf("Please enter choice: ");

    scanf("%c", &option);

    return option;
}

int getLimit ()
{
    int limit;

    scanf("%d", &limit);

    return limit;
}

int calculatePi (void)
{
    int limit,
    count = 0,
    Pi = 0;

    printf("Please enter the PI limit: ");

    limit = getLimit();

    for (count = 1; count <= limit; count++)
    {
        Pi += 1 / count;
    }

    return sqrt(Pi * 6);
}

 int calculateGeoMean()
 {
    int limit,
        userValue = 0,
        count = 0;
    double geoMean = 0;

    limit = getLimit();

    while(count <= limit)
    {
       if (userValue <= 0)
           printf("Incorrect. Try again");
       else
       {
           count++;
           userValue *= userValue;
       }

    }
    geoMean = userValue;

    return sqrt(userValue);
}

int calculateHarmonicMean()
{
    int limit,
        userValue = 0,
        count = 0;
     double harmMean = 0;

     limit = getLimit();

    while(count <= limit)
    {
        if (userValue <= 0)
            printf("Incorrect. Try again");
        else
        {
            count++;
            userValue *= 1 / userValue;
        }

    }
    harmMean = userValue;

    return limit / userValue;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function definition is totally wrong.

```
int runMenuOption (int getMenuOption())
```

either you can pass the return value of `getMenuOption` like this

```
int runMenuOption (int option)
```

or

you shouldn't pass any value to this function and call `getMenuOption` inside `runMenuOption`. You are doing both, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

```
int runMenuOption (int getMenuOption())
```

Here's your problem.

That should be:

```
int runMenuOption (int opt)
```

Also, you shouldn't be calling `getMenuOption()` within `runMenuOption` since you're calling `getMenuOption()` as you pass it to `runMenuOption` as a parameter. `runMenuOption` should only have a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the definition of your function from `int runMenuOption (int getMenuOption())` to `int runMenuOption (int option)`. In the call, `getMenuOption()` will be invoked and the output placed into the `stack frame` of the called function.

Answer (score 0):

According to your declaration of the `runMenuOption` function, it takes a pointer to a function which returns an integer as its first argument:

```
int runMenuOption (int getMenuOption())
```

The function is then called in this line:

```
option = getMenuOption();
```

This is perfectly fine. However, the problem lies in this line:

```
runMenuOption(getMenuOption());
```

Here you are calling the `getMenuOption` function and passing the return value into the `runMenuOption` function. But what you should be doing is passing the function itself as the argument:

```
runMenuOption(getMenuOption);
```

The reason you are getting a Segmentation Fault error is because the return value from the `getMenuOption` function is being treated as a function pointer, and your program is attempting to call a function at that address, which is of course invalid.

Comment: @Armin: I just tested my solution, and it works fine on GCC v4.5.3. Doing: runMenuOption(&getMenuOption) will also work, but definitely not runMenuOption(getMenuOption()). Can you please elaborate as to why you think it is wrong? EDIT: Also note, by: "runMenuOption(getMenuOption());" I'm refering to the line in which he calls runMenuOption in the main function, not the runMenuOption function prototype.

Comment: I had something different in mind, you suggestion, although unusual, works. I can't undownvote anymore until you edit.

Comment: I simply wanted to inform the author of the exact reason of the Segmentation Fault. This solution also has the advantage of requiring minimal change to the author's original program.